# VMware, macOS application cannot write to a usb pen drive while manually works

Tags: macos, vmware, nsfilemanager

I notice that a virtualized macOS can write to a USB pen drive both using the Finder or the Terminal. A program made by me instead (FileManager or NSFileManager)can't but on the host works as expected. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just curious what format the drive is running. I have noticed exFat makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed only now (long time out for the covid). Any way I tried with hfs, apfs, fat32 but exFat. I'll try, but is useless because in the case the problem still remain.